# Facing problems with actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

The "username" will not be printed when the button (action) is triggered the first time. When the button is pressed the second time, the value is printed out once. On third click the value is printed out twice..  Can someone point out my mistake?

*This is my first question, do give hints on posting better questions :D

Here's the main method:

```
public class DMS implements ActionListener{

private static String username;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    LoginFrame login = new LoginFrame();
    login.setVisible(true);    
}

public DMS(JTextField textField1) {
    DMS.username = textField1.getText();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(username);
}


}
```

And here's the action listener, which is in a jframe:

```
private void cmd_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    ActionListener actionListener = new DMS(JTextField1);
    someButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
}
```

Comment: I think that it might be due to new DMS class is created on every button click.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the answer. I've found out that my approach is totally wrong as there are 2 actionListeners to this button currently. The problem occurs as the actionListener on the main class is triggered before the "cmd_loginActionPerformed" which would initialize the value.

Comment: Accept the best answer, or write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

When the control is transferred to your action listener, you are trying to print the username that you got during the initialization - which is empty.

What you need to do is:

1. Keep a reference of the JTextField in your DMS class
2. On actionPerformed(), get the data from the component.

This will ensure that you are always fetching the latest information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried this method but the JTextField is set to private automatically by NetBeans. How can i change that?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this statement from `cmd_loginActionPerformed` so that its not being invoked every time an `ActionEvent` occurs

```
someButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

Comment: I'm using netbean to create the JFrame. After adding the actionListener to the constructor, values doesn't seem to get passed on the main class. How should i change my code?

Comment: Very difficult to determine - Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for better help

Answer (score 0):

username will assigned  once at the time of DMS object creation.

```
public DMS(JTextField textField1) {
      DMS.username = textField1.getText(); 
}
```

To get the last value from the form we need to call `getText();` from the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    DMS.username = textField1.getText(); 
    System.out.println(username);
}
```

Comment: the second part of the code returns me error as textField1 does not exists in this class. TextField1 is on another class (a JFrame)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shown the complete code, it cannot be seen when cmd_loginActionPerformed is called, but from the described behavior, it seems you are adding an action listener every time an action happens. You need to attach an action listener only once (this will fix your **incremental** printing), and that has to be done before any user action occurs, i.e. do it in initialization (this will fix the non-print issue on **first** action).